# Subdivide python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to write a method which takes a dict in the form of `{a: 1, b-c: 2, b-d: 3, e-f-g: 4}` and returns `{a: 1, b: {c: 2, d: 3}, e: {f: {g: 4}}}`. Basically split the keys containing `-` into subdicts. I've tried to do it iteratively and recursively but I got stuck. Any tips?

Comment: Please add an example of what you've tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` with recursion:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = {'a': 1, 'b.c': 2, 'b.d': 3, 'e.f.g': 4}
def group(d):
   nd = defaultdict(list)
   for [a, *b], c in d:
      nd[a].append([b, c])
   return {a:b[0][-1] if not any(j for j, _ in b) else group(b) for a, b in nd.items()}

result = group([[a.split('.'), b] for a, b in d.items()])
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2, 'd': 3}, 'e': {'f': {'g': 4}}}
```